# Why is 'remotes/origin/HEAD' sometimes mapped to 'origin/master' and sometimes not?

Tags: git, github

In some of my repositories I see...

```
> git branch --all
* master
  remotes/origin/master
```

...whilst in others I see:

```
> git branch --all
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
```

The former strikes me as correct, the latter makes me uneasy. What's going on here?

I've previously included an additional `common` branch mapped to a different repository and setting this up may have caused the issue. This additional branch has now been removed but this odd setup in the latter repository is still there. There are no additional remotes in either repository, just the standard `origin` one.

It seems to me that, in the first, `remotes/origin/master` is an abbreviation for `remotes/origin/master -> origin/master`. Only when the local and remote branches differ in some respect does the mapping need to be spelled out explicitly? So there is this odd `remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master` mapping, if that is the word for it, which seems to be taking precedence?

Answer (score 7):

[Mark Adelsberger's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47980150/1256452) covers how you *get* these (`git clone` makes them).  But let's look more generally at branch names, and then what Git calls *references* and *symbolic references*.

You already know that branch names are relatively simple: they're just strings like `master` and `develop`.  And, thanks to `git branch --all` output, you also know that you have what Git sometimes calls *remote-tracking branch names* like `origin/master`.  I prefer to call these *remote-tracking names*, so as to avoid using the word "branch" too much.

What you may not know is that both of these are just specialized forms of how Git lumps everything together.  A regular branch name like `master` is actually a *reference* whose full name is spelled `refs/heads/master`.  A remote-tracking name like `origin/master` is a reference whose full name is spelled `refs/remotes/origin/master`.  Tags, too, are just references whose full name starts with `refs/tags/`.

If you run `git branch -r`, which lists only the remote-tracking names, you'll see `origin/master` instead of `remotes/origin/master`.  This is because Git is not always consistent about how much of the `refs/remotes/` part it strips off.  (*Why* Git is inconsistent here, I don't know.)  In general Git likes to shrink these things down to something more manageable, though.  Since *all* references *always* start with `refs/`—that's [how Git *defines* them](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitglossary.html#def_ref)—you can, in general, always drop the `refs/` part, and usually more: you can usually<sup>1</sup> drop `refs/heads/`, `refs/remotes/`, and `refs/tags/`.

What a reference does for you—well, a very important part of what each reference does—is to save one of those big ugly Git hash IDs that you've seen in, e.g., `git log` output.  Internally, Git *needs* those hash IDs.  They're quite impossible for mere humans to work with, though, so Git gives us names we can use to remember the IDs.

But there's a special case allowed for *any* reference, although it's wisest to reserve it for ones that use the word `HEAD`.  Any reference can be a *symbolic* reference.  Instead of containing a big ugly hash ID, a reference can contain the name of another reference.  Git will then turn the name into the hash ID stored in the *other* reference.

Thus, if `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD` contains the *name* `refs/remotes/origin/master`, you can say `origin/HEAD` anywhere you could say `origin/master`.  This isn't much help—I, at least, find it harder to type `origin/HEAD` with its all-uppercase `HEAD`—but Git adds yet another special case: if you use the name `origin` by itself, in a place where Git "wants" a hash ID, Git will notice that `origin` corresponds to `refs/remotes/origin/`, then see that `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD` exists.  Git will read it and see that `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD` is a symbolic reference to `refs/remotes/origin/master`.  Git will read *that* and see a hash ID—and now Git will know the hash ID you meant.

So, if `origin/HEAD` (or `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD`) "points to" `origin/master`, that means you can write `origin` in a few places where you would ordinarily have to write out `origin/master`.

You can manipulate these special remote-tracking `HEAD` names using [the `git remote` command](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html), specifically with its `set-head` sub-command.  I never actually bother with any of this myself—I just type in `origin/master` when I mean that, and ignore the symbolic `HEAD`s that go with these remote-tracking names.  But if you like them, they are there for you to use.

---

<sup>1</sup>I say "usually" here because there is a special case: if you accidentally have, say, the name `foo` as both a branch name (`refs/heads/foo`) *and* a tag name (`refs/tags/foo`), it suddenly becomes a problem to just say `foo`.  One solution is to spell out `heads/foo` and `tags/foo`, or even `refs/heads/foo`.  There are more details on this, and much more, in [the gitrevisions documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, appreciated. I still can't fathom exactly what's going on but I have a slightly better understanding and it seems that nothing's broken at least!

Comment: Yes, it's normal enough; it's also useless in my (biased) opinion and can just be ignored. (At one point, back in early Git 1.6-ish days, I would unset them, but there's no real need.)

Comment: I'm just re-reading your answer, to do it justice. It seems that `origin\HEAD -> origin\master` is kind of a symbolic link? It all seems pretty pointless to me.

Comment: If you're familiar with symlinks: yes, and in fact, the original implementation of a symbolic reference was via symlink. It got changed to "plain file with special text contents" to accommodate Windows.

Comment: Can you tell me how to unset it, if it's possible? But don't worry if you can't be bothered.

Comment: That same `git remote` command has all the goop in it: `git remote set-head origin --delete` means "delete the symbolic `HEAD` for `origin`". As I mentioned above, I used to do that (back when it required manual intervention, `git remote set-head` did not exist yet) but there's no real point.

Comment: Not that I'm not grateful, of course! The command `git remote set-head -d origin` did the trick. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

The line `remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master` just tells you which branch `origin` has checked out - which in turn is the default branch checked out in a new clone.

(I probably should say, which branch `origin` *had* checked out when last the local `remotes/origin/HEAD` ref was updated.  In my tests, this ref has only been updated when the clone is initially created.  There may be ways I haven't thought of to force it to update.)

If you have a repo where you *don't* see this line, it probably means that no branch was checked out at the time the clone was made - e.g. if you cloned an empty repository.

Comment: The `git remote` command will let you set `remotes/<name>/HEAD`. Not much in Git actually uses it, though (the main use is that when parsing revision names, Git will handle `remotes/<name>` by noticing that `remotes/<name>/HEAD` exists and resolve it to its link-target, in order to resolve the hash ID).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm still confused, but it seems I have done nothing wrong and nothing's broken, so no matter.

Comment: I take that back. It now kind of all makes sense.