# What is the usage of reference `remotes/origin/HEAD`?

Tags: git

```
$ git branch -a
* master
  mongodbutils
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/mongodbutils
  remotes/origin/feature1
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/mongodbutils
```

What is the usage of reference `remotes/origin/HEAD`?

Specifically, is `remotes/origin/HEAD` used  during any of `git clone, fetch, pull, push` or other commands that operate between two repositories?

Comment: This is not *quite* a duplicate, but see https://stackoverflow.com/q/47978081/1256452 (both answers) and https://stackoverflow.com/q/8839958/1256452.